# Disable writing in depth buffer from glsl

Tags: opengl, glsl, alphablending, depth-buffer

All geometry is storing in one VBO (Transparent + Not transparent). I can not sort geometry. How I can disable writing in depth buffer from glsl without loss the data colors?

Comment: i should to shorting polygons in vbo in next rules: detecting not transparent polygons and moving his in the beginning of VBO, then drawing. It's right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand right, you want to disable depth writes because you draw both opaque and transparent objects. Apart from the fact that it doesn't work that way from within GLSL, it would not produce what you want, if it did.

If you just disabled depth writes *ad hoc*, the opaque objects coming after a transparent object would overwrite it, regardless of the z order.

What you really want to do is this:

1. Enable depth writes and depth test
2. Draw all opaque geometry. If you can, in a roughly sorted (*roughly* is good enough!) order, closest objects first.
3. Disable depth writes, keep depth test enabled
4. Enable blending
5. Draw transparent objects, sorted in the opposite direction, that is farthest away first. This occludes transparent objects with opaque geometry and makes blending work correctly.

If, for some reason, you can't sort the *opaque* geometry (though there is really no reason why you can't do that?), never mind -- it will be slightly slower because it does not cull fragments, but it will produce the same image.

If, for some reason, you can't sort the *transparent* geometry, you will have to expect incorrect results where several transparent objects overlap. This may or may not be noticeable (especially if the order is "random", i.e. changes frame by frame, it will be very noticeable -- otherwise you might in fact get away with it although it's incorrect).

Note that as datenwolf has pointed out already, the fact that several objects are in one VBO does not mean you can't draw a subset of them, or several subsets in any order you want. After all, a VBO only holds some vertices, it is up to you which groups of them you draw in which order.

Comment: I don't understand why such a burden is thrown on the client code. It's a thousand times easier to do after the fragment processing automaticaly and would boost performance a lot not involving computations on CPU. I'm geting more and more convinced that OpenGL dont use their brain when writing this more and more stupid standards.

Comment: @lukasz1985: The reason why it's such a burden is that you have a single depth value only. A scene with transparent objects has several depths per fragment where objects overlap, but you can only keep one (the closest-to-eye opaque one). For transparent objects, the Z order in which they're drawn on any given fragment is not well-defined (OpenGL cannot know a priori) but it greatly matters for the outcome. Therefore, you must sort them at application level. Using atomic ops and "fat" buffers, it is possible to do the "thousand times easier" way that you envision, but this has huge demands...

Comment: ... both on memory, and bandwidth, and it only runs on very recent hardware, and it is not entirely trivial to do either (see [here](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/SDK/10/direct3d/Source/StencilRoutedKBuffer/doc/StencilRoutedKBuffer.pdf) for an example of such a thing). OpenGL has to take into account hardware that is not top of the line as well, and it still has to work when you don't two-digit gigabytes of video memory available. Hence it unluckily can't be all that evolved.

Comment: It should have been implemented by OpenGL in the early beginnings. It's obvious that with 3d setup such issuess would come up easily. This was the first thing to consider. And dont tell me that it's complicated, it's f***n easy as hell. Having alpha, color and z buffer its easy to mix the three by a simple formula to have decent results. 
"Advanced" hardware. Yeah, right. Most advanced operation in the graphical card is the perspective division if You take a deep look. The programmer has to know advanced linear algebra to actually do anything in the 3d space with the programmable pipeline.

Comment: @lukasz1985: Well, no... "advanced" means stuff like atomic operations on textures and buffer objects, implementing per-fragment linked lists within the frame buffer and sorting them in a shader. That kind of simple stuff. It is really not _that_ f**n easy if you want predictable, reproducable, correct results (which is something OpenGL generally tries to assert). It is only trivial to whack some objects together with alpha if you don't care whether the result is correct (and remains correct when objects in the scene move). Or, of course, if there's ever only one transparent object.

Comment: Graphics hardware in the "early beginnings" of OpenGL (that is, the 1990s) was nowhere near able to deliver any such thing, neither memory-wise, nor in bandwidth, nor in ALU, nor in general functionality or programmability (neither is hardware from around 2009). Thing is, you're comparing apples and oranges. Certainly you can trivially alpha-blend objects (without sorting and such), but it's not the same thing, it's at best a very poor hack, and the outcome is kind of "random luck".

Comment: Think what's easier, a lot easier to do: To create such a solution on hardware side, standarize it and implement or let every developer struggle with scenegraph, alpha blending and geometry sorting in the nearest - farest order, what actually means to develop sort of own z-buffer on the CPU side driving the performance down drastically. Answer yourself.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the sorting of opaque objects too (for performance). As the important point of emphasis in this algorithm is the sorting of transparent object, most articles don't mention this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

> I can not sort geometry.

Why? You think because it's all in one VBO? Then I've got good news: It's perfectly possible to draw from just a subset of a buffer object.